# How to remove trial version watermark in canvasjs using Jquery (without license)

Tags: chart.js, canvasjs

I am creating chart using canvasjs. But trial version watermark appears on the bottom of the chart. Is there anyway to remove this mark?

[image: example]

Comment: What are looking for by tagging chart.js.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are using the trial version of CanvasJS. This comes with "Trial Version" watermark in the footer.

Upgrading to commercial version will remove the "trial version" watermark. Upgrading to commercial version is a breeze, and all your existing code will continue to work. Your charts will look fully professional without any watermarks.

You can upgrade to the commercial version at https://canvasjs.com/license/